# AWS cron is not running at the specified time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up a cron for amazon elasticbeanstalk worker. It is supposed to run at the 15th minute of every hour. Here is my cron configuration(yaml file)

```
    version: 1
    cron:
     - name: "cron-name"
       url: "/application/execute"
       schedule: "15 * * * *"
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks), the worker automatically picks up this cron.yaml file from source bundle and runs the cron as per the config.

***There are instances on regular basis where it doesn't run at the expected minute, few times cron doesn't run at all. Is there anything wrong with my config? Is there any known issue with amazon's cron?***

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been using scheduled tasks on an EB worker instance via cron for several months with no issues. How can you tell that the timing is off or that the task isn't being run? I would look at your SQS queues, specifically your dead-letter queue, to see if the messages are ending up there somehow.

Comment: @Brian there are two things we first do when cron hits the API => 1. log it. 2. send a slack message that cron hit the server. That way we know that it's off by a random number of minutes. Also, I have seen few occurrences of not running the cron at all. As mentioned earlier, this doesn't happen all the time but randomly.

Comment: i have encountered the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The cron expression you are using `15 * * * *` only executes at the 15th minute of every hour (e.g., 2:15, 3:15, etc.).

To execute every 15 minutes, the expression should be:

```
*/4 * * * *
```

OR

```
0,15,30,45 * * * *
```

Extrapolating from these examples on the AWS docs.

[image: AWS docs]

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html)

Examples from [here](https://medium.com/@joelennon/running-cron-jobs-on-amazon-web-services-aws-elastic-beanstalk-a41d91d1c571) also helped me:

[image: Cron expression examples]